# Entity Framework CTP5

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity-framework-ctp5

I am starting a fairly complex web app and really want to use EF CTP5 but I do not want to shoot myself in the foot here if they make any major changes just before they release it.

I know there are a lot of people using it but was wondering if anyone is currently using it in development of production apps?

Comment: You can also check this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949866/how-mature-felxible-is-the-entity-frameworks-code-first-library

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty much committed to using Code First for my production app.  I'm sure there will be a few breaking changes, but the overall API is stable.  The [MSDN ADO blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/) has just published a huge series of How-To's, so you can assume that they are nearing release and that there won't be any major changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using code first in a greenfield environment. The domain model is working well with mapping so far. 1 month into using developing it and am only excited so far. No big roadblocks. The only thing is that enum support is very tricky. I did manage to get a working specification pattern developed as well. MyFoos.Where(specPattern.Expression).